# Python: decode to url format

Tags: python, encoding, urllib, urlencode

I need convert kyrillic

```
Астрахань
```

to

```
%C0%F1%F2%F0%E0%F5%E0%ED%FC
```

I try to use

```
urllib.parse.quote_plus()
```

bit it returns

```
%D0%90%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C
```

What should I use to convert to another format?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch01s24.html) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could guess that you are using Windows cp1251 encoding. `quote_plus` uses by default utf_8, but also support any specific one:

```
>>> print(urllib.parse.quote_plus('Астрахань', encoding='cp1251'))
%C0%F1%F2%F0%E0%F5%E0%ED%FC
```